# How to let GUI browser display HTML as soon as possible (dont wait for font/javascript/CSS resources been loaded)?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet-explorer, opera

China CCP government is blocking Google services heavily recently, I can't even use basic Google search service now.

So if websites are using Google services like http://ajax.googleapis.com  http://fonts.googleapis.com, then these sites are loading *very slow*, but in fact all the HTML code are already fully loaded (I can view the source code from browser), it's just waiting for fonts/CSS/JavaScript resources to be loaded.

**So how to let GUI browser display HTML content as soon as possible, like the TUI browsers (w3m, elinks, lynx. they don't need/support font or javascript resources)?**

Currently, I'm using Firefox in Fedora linux OS, sometimes Chrome or Opera. sometimes IE in Windows OS. IE in Windows loaded pages quicker than other browsers in linux, I guess the timeout mechanism of IE is shorter than others, my guess could be wrong.

Comment: For Opera, have you tried changing the setting of `Preferences > Advanced > Browsing > Loading`?

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter, even set to "redraw instantly" (default is "redraw after 3 seconds"), pages are still not displayed instantly. see the screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/QeRU18u.png

Comment: Hmm, how about looking at the "Network" tab of Dragonfly (or Chrome's inspector, etc.) while reloading the page? That should give you some idea of what's taking up the loading time on any given page.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter, [Firefox 30, cache was cleaned](http://i.imgur.com/39Ksor5.png), i think the ajax.googleapis.com network activity is wrong in this screenshot. and [Chrome 36](http://i.imgur.com/Zr8OSBs.png)

Comment: So weird, when I try use Opera Dragonfly to analyze, Google services are seems become ok now, it's had been blocked for 1.5 month.

Comment: Glad to hear it's working again... I agree that it's weird, though.

Comment: @AmosM.Carpenter, it doesn't keeps for a long time, after half a day, Google services are blocked again by the [GFW](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Great_Firewall). So this question still need an answer.  btw, Opera Dragonfly screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/mQel6HD.png (superuser.com)  and http://i.imgur.com/4ui28bh.png (www.google.com.hk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find a workaround for this issue:

For Firefox browser:

- Install [FoxyProxy](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/foxyproxy-standard) addon
- Create a new proxy in FoxyProxy, and the proxy host & port could be anything valid. it can point to a non-existed proxy.
- Add a new URL Pattern for this proxy, named it as "Google" or something else, the URL pattern is `*google*`, so now all requests to URLs containing `google` will be *routed* to this proxy.

For Chrome browser, there's a similar addon: [Proxy SwitchySharp](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dpplabbmogkhghncfbfdeeokoefdjegm).

This workaround is not perfect, but it works in most time.

Answer (score 0):

You can [use Google Mobilizer (if that service isn't blocked) or AdBlock Chrome extension](http://mvark.blogspot.in/2014/07/how-to-block-font-css-javascript-files.html) to view plain text web pages without the dependent font, JavaScript, CSS files